# How to fit a Tabulator table to a div of fixed height and width?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabulator

I am trying to create a Tabulator table inside a div that has fixed height and width.

However, if there is not enough columns/rows of data to fill the entire width or height of the div, the Tabulator table will still occupy the entire height/width, only filling grey color in the free space.

How can I get rid of this grey area? Note that I do not want to resize rows nor columns.

```js
 function create_table() {
    let table = new Tabulator("#table", {
        data: [
            {name: 'John', surname: 'Miller'},
            {name: 'Mike', surname: 'Tyson'},                        
        ],
        columns:[
            {title: 'Name', field: 'name'},
            {title: 'Surname', field: 'surname'},
        ]
    })               
  }
                
 create_table()
```

```css
#table {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <!-- Tabulator -->
            <link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.2.7/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.2.7/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="table"></div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Using this approach, If we have 100 rows then overflowing rows will be hidden. And don't try to set overflow: scroll because you'll lose virtualDOM advantage & everything will be rendered at once which will make the browser very slow.

Comment: This question still remains unanswered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment you have one of two display options for the table:

- If you specify a height on the table it will take up that height and any overflow will be managed correctly and allow scrolling, if there are not enough rows to fill the table it still takes up the same amount of space and you see the table background
- If you don't specify a height on the table it assumes that you want it to take up as much height as there are rows and that the external div to the table will handle scrolling

So in your scenario you could look at changing the background color to make it fit in more, but there is no way to hid the extra space.

In the upcoming version 4.6 (coming early 2020) there will be a new display mode that is a hybrid between the two, that will allow the table to expand until it overflows and then handle scrolling inside the table

Answer (score 0):

I have changed `height` to `max-height`. Does this solve your problem? No matter how many rows, the table will not occupy more than `200px` in height.

Have also added `display: inline-block` and `max-width: 200px` to adjust the containing `div`'s width. You can make the table scrollable in any or both directions once the table width and/or height reaches the maximum defined in it's containing `div`.

```js
 function create_table() {
    let table = new Tabulator("#table", {
        data: [
            {name: 'John', surname: 'Miller'},
            {name: 'Mike', surname: 'Tyson'},                        
        ],
        columns:[
            {title: 'Name', field: 'name'},
            {title: 'Surname', field: 'surname'},
        ]
    })               
  }
                
 create_table()
```

```css
#table {
  display: inline-block;
  max-height: 200px;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <!-- Tabulator -->
            <link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.2.7/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.2.7/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="table"></div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
ar selectedCount = function() {
  var selectedRows = $("#example-table").tabulator("getSelectedRows").length;
  $('#rowCount').text(selectedRows);
}

$("#example-table").tabulator({
  height: 205,
  layout: "fitColumns", //fit columns to width of table (optional)
  columns: [ {title: 'Name', field: 'name'},
            {title: 'Surname', field: 'surname'}
  ],
});

var tabledata = [
            {name: 'John', surname: 'Miller'},
            {name: 'Mike', surname: 'Tyson'},                        
        ];

//load sample data into the table
$("#example-table").tabulator("setData", tabledata);


selectedCount();
```

```html
<div id="example-table"></div>

<p>
  Number of selected rows = <span id="rowCount"></span>
</p>
```

```
As per my understanding, Please check the documentation provided to make the 
columns to fit for the parent container http://tabulator.info/examples/4.4?#fittowidth


Please check the working example in the following https://jsfiddle.net/gzx72ukh/
```

Comment: Please see my question, I do not want to make columns fit/resize them. I want to keep them as they are and get rid of the grey area.

Comment: Please check the updated fiddle [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b48gcy6t/)